# Significant performance degradation when not converting to datetime first

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I am seeing a performance hit (2x-3x slower) in a query when I use strings for a date in the middle of a query, as opposed to putting the string value into a variable of type `smalldatetime` first.  So *e.g.*

```
declare @rptDate AS smalldatetime
set @rtpDate = CAST('2014-06-22' AS smalldatetime)
SELECT SUM(tons) FROM sales
 WHERE ItemClass IN (1, 3, 5, 7) 
   AND AcctNo LIKE '31_-30[12]0'
   AND YEAR(InvDate) = YEAR(@rptDate) 
   AND MONTH(InvDate) = MONTH(@rptDate) '
   AND DAY(InvDate) <= DAY(@rptDate)
```

is definitely faster than

```
SELECT SUM(tons) FROM sales
 WHERE ItemClass IN (1, 3, 5, 7) 
   AND AcctNo LIKE '31_-30[12]0'
   AND YEAR(InvDate) = YEAR('2014-06-22') 
   AND MONTH(InvDate) = MONTH('2014-06-22') 
   AND DAY(InvDate) <= DAY('2014-06-22')
```

So why is "the proper optimization" not happening here?

Comment: Have you tried making three separate vars for `@month`, `@day`, and `@year`?

Comment: If needs to parse the string to date every row.  And it may kill use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would go one further

```
declare @rptDate AS smalldatetime
declare @year as int 
declare @month as int
declare @day as int
set @rtpDate = CAST('2014-06-22' AS smalldatetime)
set @year  = year(@rtpDate)
set @month = month(@rtpDate)
set @day   = day(@rtpDate)

SELECT SUM(tons) FROM sales
 WHERE ItemClass IN (1, 3, 5, 7) 
   AND AcctNo LIKE '31_-30[12]0'
   AND YEAR(InvDate)  = @year 
   AND MONTH(InvDate) = @month
   AND DAY(InvDate)  <= @day
```

Comment: I realize this can be optimized.  What I'm really looking for is why can't SQL Server do this optimization on its own.  It seems like this is an obvious case where it should.  Is there something inherent to T-SQL or SQL Server that I'm missing why it can't?

Comment: I'm really trying to understand the inner workings of SQL Server here.  I actually need to put this in a view, so it's not an option to create variables in this case.